# structure flowchart type data in a database

Tags: sql, database-design, flowchart

I'm trying to decide how to structure information in a database. I have a series of questions each with answers, and based on the answers selected it moves onto a different set of questions.  A flow chart as such. What is the best way to structure and work with this kind of data?

Comment: This question is way too broad for SO. Can you break it down into more manageable pieces, perhaps along with some things that you have tried?

Comment: You want to research database normalization.  [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization . That's a good place to start. Good luck

Comment: While a little vague, I don't believe this question is too broad. It describes a general, but easy to understand, data structure, and asks how one would represent it in a database.

Answer (score 1):

A [flowchart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flowchart) is generally a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29) or [directed graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) structure, meaning a reasonable way to represent it in a database is with a parent-child relationship.

Consider the following tables:

```
questions
| id | question                        |
|  1 | What is your name?              |
|  2 | What is your quest?             |
|  3 | What is your favorite color?    |
|  4 | What is your quest?             |
|  5 | What is the capital of Assyria? |

answers
| id | question_id | next_question | answer                   |
|  1 |           1 |             2 | Sir Launcelot of Camelot |
|  2 |           2 |             3 | To seek the Holy Grail   |
|  3 |           3 |          NULL | Blue                     |
|  4 |           1 |             4 | Sir Robin of Camelot     |
|  5 |           4 |             5 | To seek the Holy Grail   |
```

We represent questions as nodes in a tree, connected to one or more answers, which in turn point to a next question.

```
                          a3 - NULL
                        /
                a2 - q3
              /
      a1 - q2 
   /
q1 
   \
      a4 - q4
              \
                a5 - q5
```

Some example queries:

```
-- Get all possible answers for the root question
SELECT * FROM answers WHERE question_id = 1;

-- Get the next question given a selected answer
SELECT * FROM questions WHERE id = 4;
```

As you can likely see, this isn't perfect.  In particular, in this example the same question can potentially lead to different future choices, meaning we have to duplicate the question (`q2` and `q4`), however this does make some sense if we think about the questions and answers in terms of the whole tree, rather than as individual questions on their own - though the text of the question is the same, its context leads to different future questions.  It will depend on your use-case whether you'll need to consider such cases.

You'll note also that it's possible for there to both be no further question, and for there to be no acceptable answers.  You should similarly decide how you want to handle this, but one possibility would be for you to create another table, `actions`, which could be pointed at either from a `no_answer_action` column in `questions`, or an optional `action` column in `answers`, e.g.:

```
actions
| id | action                               |
|  1 | Cast into the Gorge of Eternal Peril |
|  2 | The other side he see                |
```

By using this parent-child relationship, you are effectively creating a [one-to-many mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinality_%28data_modeling%29) between questions and their answers.  You may find you need a many-to-many relationship (though in a flow chart, I'd think not) if your data is complicated enough, in which case you have a table for questions, and a table for answers, and an additional table listing the pairings of questions and answers.

<sub>Credit Monty Python: http://www.sacred-texts.com/neu/mphg/mphg.htm#Scene%2035</sub>

Comment: +1 Q: What is the capital of Assyria? Q: What is the airspeed velocity of an unladen swallow?

Comment: I leave finishing this flowchart as an exercise for the reader :P

Comment: What manner of man are you that can summon up fire without flint or tinder?